How is summation by parts technique used in this derivation?
In this answer, whuber comments that the technique used in the answer is summation by parts:

The discrete case, assume that $X \ge 0$ takes non-negative integer
values. Then we can write the expectation as  $$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \E X = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \P(X=k) $$ Now, we will first write this as a double sum, and then
change the order of summation. Observe that $k = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 1$
(the case $k=0$ gives an upper limit that is smaller than the lower
limit, we take that as the empty sum, which is zero). This gives $$   
\E X = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 1 \cdot \P(X=k) $$ Now, in
this double sum we sum first on $j$, which clearly goes to $\infty$.
Observe that in the inner summation the indices satisfy the inequality
$$
 0 \le j \le k-1 $$ Solving that for $k$ gives $ k \ge j+1$, which then gives the limits of summation in the new inner sum: $$ \E X = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=j+1}^\infty \P(X=k) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \P(X > j) $$ which is the result.  The continuous case is similar.

I went to the wikipedia to try to understand his comment but I do not get it.

Suppose $\{f_k\}$ and $\{g_k\}$ are two sequences. Then,
$$
\sum_{k=m}^{n} f_k (g_{k+1} - g_k) = (f_{n+1} g_{n+1} - f_m g_m) - \sum_{k=m}^{n} g_{k+1} (f_{k+1} - f_k). 
$$

In what way is rearranging the sums related to summation by parts?

Hint: try $f_k=k.$

Ok since whuber commented, I decided to look back into it and figured it out.
I think the following expression from wikipedia makes it easier to understand:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n f_k g_k = f_0 \sum_{k=0}^n g_k + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (f_{j+1} - f_j) \sum_{k=j+1}^n g_k.
$$
Also as whuber hinted:
$$
f_k =  \sum_{i'=0}^{k-1} 1 . 
$$
So the first part of the definition is
$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^n f_k g_k  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left ( P(X=k)  \times \sum_{i'=0}^{k-1} 1 \right)
$$
So the equivalent is,
$$
f_0 \sum_{k=0}^n g_k + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (f_{j+1} - f_j) \sum_{k=j+1}^n g_k =\sum_{i'=0}^{0} 1 \times \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X=k) + \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{i'=0}^{j+1} 1 - \sum_{i''=0}^{j} 1 \right) \sum_{k=j+1}^n P(X=k)
$$
$$
= 0 + \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 1 \times \sum_{k=j+1}^{\infty} P(X>j) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} P(X>j) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 1 - P(X<j). 
$$
